# Is sharing databases's hostname considered to be a security hole?

Tags: databases, postgresql

We have a Postgres database running on a Heroku and want to setup an external connection to it from the DB management GUI application (e.g. pgAdmin)

Being novice to security things I wonder if it is considered a security hole to share a database's host/database name via any internet messaging services e.g. email, skype etc. The database credentials are NOT shared via aforementioned channels

It would be nice to have a reference to any available security standards that everyone should be aware of

Comment: It’s not a risk in its own right, but it could aid enumeration and allows an attacker to find the hostname making their life that bit easier. The risk isn’t necessarily high, especially if the messaging services is secured with end to end or point to point encryption. I see this done a lot and in my opinion it is very common practice, although probably bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hostname/database name wouldn't usually be considered "sensitive" information in that they don't directly provide access to a system, they would just allow an initial connection attempt to be made.  Leaking things like database name publicly might be considered a minor information leak, however that wouldn't apply to communicating them over e-mail/skype etc.

In the scenario you're describing (opening up database access remotely) an important control would be to limit the systems that can connect to the management interface, ideally by source IP address.  This reduces the risk of some random person connecting to the management interface and attempting to compromise it (e.g. by password guessing attacks, or vulnerability in the management software)